# How to configure a Azure MySQL DBMS software configure according to vendor guidance?

Tags: mysql, security, azure-sql-database

We currently in the process of the Implementing below Standards required.

https://www.cyber.gov.au/acsc/view-all-content/guidance/database-management-system-software

**ISM - 1246    - Hardening and configuration - DBMS software is configured according to vendor guidance**

I am confused how this can be applicable to Cloud based **Azure Managed MYSQL Database** System, As I understand When Creating Azure Cloud MySQL Databases, they are created with according to the vendor guidelines listed for MySQL. All the parameters in the Server Connections and Server Settings are setup according to the Vendor specification.

For My understanding there is nothing to do, Is there anything that i am missing here ..!

Comment: The folks at Azure should be able to tell you if their configuration is compliant with your requirements by default, and specifically where they may deviate. When it comes to security, and especially when regulatory standards are involved, don't assume anything.

Comment: I would expect a Linux-based OS to be a requirement for "hardening".